# MSSQL php pdo pagination, some thing wrong on bindParam

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Working fine with `MsSQL`:

```
$ppage = 15;
$poset = 0;
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY ID OFFSET {:$poset } ROWS FETCH NEXT {:ppage } ROWS ONLY";
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($stmt);
$stmt->execute();
return $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Not working fine with `MsSQL`:

```
$ppage = 15;
$poset = 0;
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY ID OFFSET :poffset ROWS FETCH NEXT :perpage ROWS ONLY";
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($stmt);
$stmt->bindParam(':poffset', $poset);
$stmt->bindParam(':perpage', $ppage);
$stmt->execute();
return $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

the query is fine with I use to run with variables actual data it works but it's not working when I set the variable by `bindParam`, when am I missing.

### thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `bindValue` instead:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($stmt);
$stmt->bindValue(':poffset', $poset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':perpage', $ppage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: it's working now, is there any difference on security between BindValue & bindParam ?

Comment: @Rafiq I'm not aware of any difference in security. You are still protected from SQL injection.

Comment: did for both ansers :)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using the `bindParam()` function, inside of the parameters of the `execute()` function, add an array containing the values.

Something like this:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($stmt);
$stmt->execute(array(':poffset' => $poset, ':perpage' => $ppage)); // using an array rather than the bindValue function.
```

Use it as you would normally with the `bindParam` function, but substitute the commas for `=>`.

This way of doing things will save you having to call the `bindParam()` function for each value **&** will still protect against *SQL Injection.*

Comment: If this helped you or fixed your problem, please consider upvoting or selecting as an answer. :) @Rafiq